# How split a dict that is inside a list into a df

Tags: python, pandas

trying to iterate in this dict and transform in into a df.

Problem is the for loop is not going to the second layer of the dict.

data:

```
print(related_queries)

>>>

{'HVAC': {'top':                   query  value
0          hvac near me    100
1           hvac system     58
2             hvac jobs     50
3             hvac unit     49
, 'rising':                                     query  value
0      hvac unit replacement cost near me   3700
1                              hvac memes    350
2              hvac unit replacement cost    300
3                   southern comfort hvac    250 }}
```

my code:

```
df_split = pd.DataFrame({"search":""  , "score": ""})


df_split["search"] = [[x:0][x.split("")] for x in related_queries]

df_split["score"] = [[x:1][x.split("")] for x in related_queries]
```

desired output:

```
type     search         score
top      hvac near me    100

# and so on...
```

Comment: @Ben.T, I updated the question. There are two dict. 1: ```Contains HVAC ``` , 2: ``` contains two values: top and rising```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then `reset_index`, `rename` and `drop` to meet the output:

```
#dummy input
related_queries = {'HVAC': {'top': pd.DataFrame({'query': list('abcd'), 'value':range(4)}), 
                            'end':pd.DataFrame({'query': list('efgh'), 'value':range(10,14)})}}
# concat and some cosmetic
df_f = pd.concat(related_queries['HVAC']).reset_index()\
         .rename(columns={'level_0': 'type', 'query':'search', 'value':'score'})\
         .drop('level_1', axis=1)
print (df_f)
  type search  score
0  top      a      0
1  top      b      1
2  top      c      2
3  top      d      3
4  end      e     10
5  end      f     11
6  end      g     12
7  end      h     13
```